# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Python3'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import, importerror, python-module

Using Python 3.8, issue occurred while importing. It's very simple. But any changes in way of importing in python 3 ?

Under `main` folder, below structure exists.

[image: folder_structure]

```
a1.py

import sys
print(sys.version)
from b.b1 import *

b1.py

import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

When I execute `python a/a1.py` (under `main`), it `prints python version` but errors out while importing as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a/a1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from b.b1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

It can be resolved by appending path in `a1.py` , but not the solution. Am I missing anything here or does it depend upon interpreter path ?

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
sys.path.append("path")
from b.b1 import *
```

In Pycharm, when I execute `a1.py` without `sys.path.append` (right-click, run as 'a1'), it executes. Command executed looks like below

```
/Users/a1234/venv/bin/python /Users/a1234/project_folder/main/a/a1.py
```

When I execute `a1.py` without `sys.path.append` from terminal (under main, python a/a1.py , gets `ModuleNotFoundError:` error)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

The module at a1.py cannot find the b folder, because it is already inside a folder, however this might work, if you had a python file outside the two folders a, b calling each one like your code. –

the sys.path.append(path), adds the path to the list of paths to check for importable modules, hence why it executes with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However that works fine since both modules present in same package.

Comment: Do you see anything missing in above case ? could be interpreter's path or anything in pycharm ? I'm facing this issue recently with python 3.8.

Comment: Your suspicions are right, it is indeed due to the path the ide checks, usually when someone installs python, the path to check for modules/standard library, is set by default. so when you call sys.path.append(), you are adding another path to check for importable modules.

Comment: How can it be done without sys.path.append (instead of apending everytime whenever this module imported in module of another package) ?

Comment: You'd have to go and add the path to the file in the environmental variables in advanced settings, which is more bothersome for a simple task like this. By default, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

Comment: the module at a1.py cannot find the b folder, because it is already inside a folder, however this might work, if you had a python file outside the two folders a, b calling each one like your code.